# Is there an Eclipse line-width marker?

Tags: eclipse, editor, eclipse-plugin

I have a specific project where I need to wrap every code line at 65 characters. I have set up the eclipse Java code formatter properly for this. But what I really want is a vertical line to be drawn in the editor showing where the max line width while I am typing, not just when I run the formmater. I know this feature is available in some capacity because it is displayed in the code formatter property page.

I don't see any option in eclipse to turn this on and I didn't see any plug-ins that do it on Eclipse Plugin Central

Comment: In case you are looking for a solution for the Eclipse Neon bug, check https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=468307#c11.

Answer (score 375, accepted):

Look in Windows / Preferences (at least on Windows - IIRC it moves around for different operating systems) then:

```
General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Show Print Margin
```

Tick this and it should show the line.

As a quick way of finding this, use the search filter in the top and filter on "margin".

Notes from the comments - unverified by me, but I have no reason to doubt them:

> It has changed somehow in 2016: For details see [here] (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=495490#c2) You have to set it in the formatter: From menu [Window]-->[Preferences], select [Java]-->[Code Style]-->[Formatter], and then edit your formatter profile. In the tab page [Line wrapping], you can find a setting named "Maximum line width". Change this setting, and the print margin in Java source editor will be changed too.

Comment: You should also change the line length for code formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3697302/311744

Comment: Because these can have different column values, remember to set the 'Maximum line width' to the same value as 'Print margin column'

Comment: Neon (4.6) does not have this setting :(

Comment: It has changed somehow in 2016: For details see here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=495490#c2 You have to set it in the formatter: From menu [Window]-->[Preferences], select [Java]-->[Code Style]-->[Formatter], and then edit your formatter profile.

In the tab page [Line wrapping], you can find a setting named "Maximum line width".
Change this setting, and the print margin in Java source editor will be changed too.

Comment: Please update the answer as per  Uwe Günther 's suggestion. It was necessary for me to get the line to appear at a distance > 80. Eclipse version is 2018-09

Comment: For Eclipse CDT (currently): changing "Print Margin Column" in [Window] --> [Preferences] --> [General] --> [Editors] --> [Text Editors] alone will have no effect, same issue as @UweGünther reported. However, the Java-IDE-specific solution won't work. In addition to the original solution, go to [Window] --> [Preferences] -->[C/C++] --> [Code Style] --> [Formatter] --> [Edit...] and in the [Line Wrapping] tab, set the [Maximum line width]. Supposedly, the print margin and wrapping guide may be separated in the future (see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=468307#c58).

Comment: For me, the sugguestion of @UweGünther worked only after restarting Eclipse (2021-03, on Ubuntu).

More precisely:

Answer (score 48):

In Eclipse Luna (4.4):
Choose menu **`Window\Preference`** . Look at top-left corner, in search box *`type filter text`*, type: **`margin`**.
[image]

In section **`Apperance color option`**, Choose **`Print margin`**. Choose **`Show print margin`**. In text box **`Print margin column`** , type `65` as what you want.

Comment: This answer repeats [the answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1248899/572834), with a screen shot.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov True but this answer adds to the original. The screenshot is a nice addition in general but especially because the highlighting shows how to change the color of the margin. I would have found this myself eventually because the print margin in the Luna dark theme was blinding me but this answer made my life easier which is always a good thing in an SO answer.

Comment: Is there a way to have eclipse show warning when a line is longer then the margin?

Comment: Neon (4.6) does not have this setting :(

Answer (score 7):

[@Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1248899/4561887) is incomplete.

### (1/2) First, do what he said:

`Window` --> `Preferences` --> `General` --> `Editors` --> `Text Editors` --> check the box for `Show Print Margin`

Ticking this box will show the vertical line.

[image]

As a quick way of finding this, use the search filter in the top and filter on "margin".

**However, this only shows the line, but under most situations the "Print margin column" value there is flat-out ignored.**

---

**To set the column number for where the line should be**, do what @John Percival Hackworth mentions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3697302/4561887):

### (2/2) Go to:

`Window` --> `Preferences` --> `C/C++` [or whatever language you are using] --> `Code Style` --> `Formatter` --> click `Edit` --> under the `Line Wrapping` tab set the value you desire for `Maximum line width`.

[image]

### Side note:

1. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> to toggle soft line wrapping on and off. It will soft wrap (ie: no carriage return) at the end of the screen, however, not at the column you set above.

**How do you enforce hard line wrapping at the column you set above (ie: that adds a carriage return)? I don't know yet.** If you figure it out let me know. In Sublime Text 3 (a much better editor but with a much worse indexer/function definition finder :() it's <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>.

**Update:** I think it may be possible with the "CppStyle" plugin, which uses `clang-format`, by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to apply the auto-format, but I don't know the exact instructions to make it work yet.

## Related:

1. Set tab width: [Changing editor tab width in eclipse 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650652/changing-editor-tab-width-in-eclipse-3-5/58494110#58494110)

Answer (score 0):

After some months with Espressif, but also with other brands plugged-in Eclipse, I found how to enlarge maximum line width. I made a lot of attempts and show how to do for Espressif-IDE:

**Right click a project->properties->C/C++ General->Formatter
->Enable Project specific settings->
New->Give your profile a name and base it on a built-in formatter: I choose BSD/Allman->Edit this new profile->within Line Wrapping tab type for example 200 for Maximum line width->Apply changes.**

Format source files: you'll have long lines.

Before I did the same manouvres starting from:
Window->Preferences->C/C++->code Style->Formatter... : that never worked.