# Changing editor tab width in eclipse 3.5

Tags: eclipse, tabs

I am trying to adjust the width of tabs from Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors where there is a field for "Display Tab Width". But no matter what I enter there the size of indentations when I start a newline in a Java file is 4. Any ideas?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Java files have a special place to edit this setting. You need to go to

`Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter`

And edit the profile.

Comment: this configuration is very helpful.We can even make project specific format settings. I really liked it

Comment: In eclipse you typically can't edit the builtin formatter profile. So when you make changes to the builtin profile, change it's name and save it as a new profile, the original builtin profile is still intact, this is basically a custom profile that's borrowing all of the settings from the builtin one.

Comment: On a Mac, for Eclipse Luna (4.4.1), the command is under Eclipse -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter.

Comment: it change for java code only. how about html and css?

Comment: In Lua Development Tools, the same advice applies to Lua. It has its own menu entry.

Comment: ... -> Edit -> Indentation (currently).

Comment: Great! It solved my problem, but Java is C++ in my case! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Changing Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors tab preference is relevant for text files, not for java files as indicated here. You may create a text file in Eclipse and check that your tab size is really changed.

Comment: This works for XML files.  Java files are in the formatter.  But +1 for solving it for non-Java.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Check your Java->Code Style->Formatter settings, to see whether you're using tabs or spaces; you might be using spaces!

Answer (score 2):

This setting is superseded for Java by the setting from the Code Style Formatter.

It can be found in Java / Code Style / Formatter (click Edit) / Indentation tab / Indentation

Answer (score 2):

### How to set tab size (number of spaces when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd>) in Eclipse or Eclipse CDT:

There are multiple places to check and things to do:

1. Global Preferences:
2. **Window --> Preferences --> General --> Editors --> Text Editors** --> change "Displayed tab width" from 4 to 2
3. **Window --> Preferences --> Java OR C/C++ [depending on which you're using] --> Code Style --> Formatter** --> click "Edit" button for your "Active profile" --> click "Indentation" tab on top-left --> change "Indentation size" to 2, "Tab size" to 2, and "Tab policy" to "Spaces only".
4. Project Preferences (these override the global settings for a given project):
5. **Project --> Properties** (or just **right-click on project in the folder list at the left, and go to "Properties"**) **--> Java OR "C/C++ General" [depending on what you're using] --> Formatter** --> either uncheck the box for "Enable project specific settings", OR check that box and ensure your settings are correct (refer to 1.2 above, beginning with the `click "Edit" button` step, but do it from this menu this time).
6. To test your new settings: return to your editor and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> with the cursor sitting immediately after an opening curly brace (`{`) somewhere. It should go to a new line with the proper indentation you've set above.
7. *NB: watch out! If you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on or after a line with different indentation from what you've set above, it will duplicate that wrong indentation (by copying the style of the lines just above) rather than accepting your new indentation settings. Do NOT think it isn't working in this case! It IS working! Just delete all of the old indentation and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> right after a `{` and you'll see everything works just fine.*

*Version tested:* All tested in Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a).

### Duplicate or Related Questions & Answers:

1. Google search for "Eclipse change tab size" - https://www.google.com/search?q=eclipse+change+tab+size&oq=eclipse+change+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j0l3.2483j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
2. https://superuser.com/questions/462221/how-do-i-reliably-change-the-indentation-width-in-eclipse
3. [Eclipse tab width not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681954/eclipse-tab-width-not-changing)

### Also Related

1. Set line width vertical bar marker / print margin - [Is there an Eclipse line-width marker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248895/is-there-an-eclipse-line-width-marker/49372370#49372370)

Answer (score 1):

After digging into this more deeply, I think I've figured this out:

### Java file tab DISPLAY width

Confusingly, this is under "Formatter" in preferences (like the accepted answer says). But this is inconsistent location-wise with where the option for tab display width for the non-java file Editor is located.

`/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.core/org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indentation.size=16`

### Text file tab DISPLAY width

`/instance/org.eclipse.ui.editors/tabWidth=2`

---

I emphasize DISPLAY because this is just for rendering in Eclipse. It does not change the contents of your file, and has no effect on "Source -> Format".