# Eclipse tab width not changing

Tags: java, eclipse, tabs, width

I've looked through a couple of posts related to this but they don't seem to help me solve my problem. I have a project where the java files are indented with a 2-space width. I would like to change everything to 4-space width. I tried the "correct indentation" option but it just moves everything back to a 2-space width when I modify a few lines to 4-space indentation. I've checked settings in Java->Code Style->Formatter and the default is 4-space width. I've also checked settings at General->Editors->Text Editors and they are set to 4-space tab width.

I thought the correct indentation may have been reading the whole java file and correcting the code so it conforms to everything else in the file, so I manually modified every line to have 4-space width indentation. Autocorrect indentation still takes everything back to 2 spaces. Has anyone had this problem before? Is there another setting to change?

Comment: Sounds strange. Are you using Tab to indent and set the tab-size to 2 or using 4-spaces to indent?

Comment: Have you tried simply re-importing your code formatter (i.e. change and change back)

Comment: What do you mean by re-importing the code formatter? You probably don't mean this, but after I make the changes, I have done Eclipse->Restart to close everything out, save the settings, and open up again. Still no luck though.

Comment: New answer with additional info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650652/changing-editor-tab-width-in-eclipse-3-5/58494110#58494110

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. The project-specific settings had the indentation width set to 2, not 4. These settings must have overridden the eclipse settings.

Comment: Is this for FORMATTING text (i.e. modifying), or for DISPLAY (i.e. read only). Mine still has the issue you described but the project-specific setting doesn't have anything for display width, only the formatter.