# Is there a way to remove "vertical ruler" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Hello i have searched for remooving vertical ruller from eclipse for some time and i havent found any solution. It is not listed even in the Help section of Eclipse.

Does anyone happen to know, how to remove or disable it?

Comment: What do you mean with 'vertical ruler'? The thin strip at the left of the editor holding breakpoints, folding marks, etc.?

Comment: Programmatically you can avoid one in your own subclass by returning null from AbstractTextEditor#createVerticalRuler(), but as a user, no.  Why would you want to?

Comment: I want to remove the vertical ruler **on the right**. But I don't find a way, in the Prefs. Any solution ?

Comment: [Now I know how to remove the annoying vertical ruler on the right.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1248899/1824094)

Comment: @SteveAtkinson Because it breaks mousewheel vertical scrolling. In Preferences/PyDev/Editor/Overview Ruler Minimap, deselecting
'Show Minimap?' and selecting 'Show vertical scrollbar?' fixed mousewheel vertical scrolling. Eclipse 4.5.0 20150621-1200, GTK, Linux.

Comment: @SteveAtkinson Also it takes up a lot more horizontal space than a standard vertical scrollbar, and I don't find it useful at all. How is it 'incredibly useful' to you?

Comment: If you are talking about the "Folding" then right click on that left line and see the option "Folding", just uncheck the "Enable Folding" and then the line will be 'almost' gone. You can always bring back the line by following the same process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only configure what is shown in the vertical ruler using Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations. You cannot disable it.

Comment: Looks like hiding the overview ruler was possible in older Eclipse versions - [link](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=cGYMActRiakC&lpg=PA55&ots=vBruIdrO8o&dq=eclipse%20hide%20overview%20ruler&pg=PA55#v=onepage&q=eclipse%20hide%20overview%20ruler&f=false)

Answer (score 17):

For me it only shows up in PyDev, you can easily disable it from:

Preferences → PyDev → Editor → Overview Ruler Minimap →
Uncheck Show Minimap & Show Overview Items in Minimap.

Done and done! You should check show vertical scroll bars if you're disabling the mini-map

Comment: Thanks for this, I had this issue with PyDev as well. I wasn't against the Minimap but the way Eclipse showed it irritated me, I didn't find any purpose for it (unlike other editors). Its disabled now. Peace!

Comment: I had to restart Eclipse for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the minimap width to 10 made it best of both worlds.  used to be much smaller in older versions of eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it.

- `Window` → `Preferences` → `General` → `Editors` → `Text Editors`
- Uncheck `Show print margin`.
- Done!