# Is there a way to remove vertical ruler in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I basically had the very same question as [Is there a way to remove "vertical ruler" in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12825710/1184842) (word by word) but didn't mean the annotations ruler, but the print margin ruler. I didn't know it's the print margin ruler, thats why I searched by "vertical ruler" and was mislead to the wrong answer (from my point of view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched with "vertical ruler" for what I now know is called the "print margin". If someone else searched for this too: It can be changed in

```
Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors
```

The Option is called: "Show print margin"

[image]