# Is there any option for knowing characters in a line (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax

Lately I've been reading the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf), and I noticed that lines shouldn't have more that 80 characters, and because I work in a 24 inch screen the code lines can be quite large and I still can read it easily, so the question is:

Does eclipse has any option to read code lines, like in the vertical way?

If not is there any option I could use?

Comment: If you are working on a team, there may be a formatting convention for the codebase.  So even if the formatting were changed on your setup, the changes would be taken out each time you save or commit.

Comment: Personally, I've never once followed that code convention. I can't stand having `println()` statements, function calls, function declarations/etc split up into several lines. To me, that's the hardest stuff to read. I ended up changing Eclipse's settings to allow 160 characters per line....

Comment: I think this might be what you're looking for?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248895/is-there-an-eclipse-line-width-marker

Comment: i got eclipse setting of auto-format code , guess it should auto-follow general standards

Comment: If I should add, if you want to do it on the fly (by habit I do this) hit CTRL+F on Windows (Linux too?); I think it would be Cmnd+F on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I use Eclipse Kepler.

From the toolbar, Click on Window and select Preferences.

In Preferences, Expand General-->Editors-->Text Editors.

Enable Show Print Margin. 
The default is 80 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the bottom and a little to the right of the IDE window by having selected a line, you can see this (active by default):

[image: Bottom of Eclipse]

Where the pair 246:103 is a line:column pair (image works as an example).

I suggest though that you follow a coding convention agreed between your coding team, or even your own for a good coding style if you want. This coding convention was applied in old ages - in fact, it came out of [IBM punch cards](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148677/why-is-80-characters-the-standard-limit-for-code-width) and was useful in small terminals. Of course, you are free to follow this convention if you want, in order to be in line with the book.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a coding team :( ..... Jajaja thanks for the extra info man